# Unable to run executables (.exe, .bat) from removable device on Windows 10

Tags: windows, executable, usb-drive, group-policy

When I try to execute a software on an USB-drive (commercial software incl. license), I receive the following message on my brand new Windows 10 computer:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

On my old computer (Windows 2000) this worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the reason for this message is a group policy which prohibits the execution of files from removable devices. Specifically, the settings for this policy can be found in the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc), Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Removable Storage Access > Removable Disks: Deny execute access. If this policy is enabled, you will not be able to start .exe, .cmd, .bat and the like directly from the USB-drive.

Your company may prohibit changes to the settings of this group policy for your system. On the other hand, those group policies could be restricted to specific user groups, i.e. if you can be assigned to a different user group, that restriction could be removed for you.

A better option would be to install your software on you computer directly or on a network drive.

Be aware that USB-drives are potential loopholes for malware: The USB-drive you use today might not be the same as the one you used yesterday... So it is certainly better not to start any executable from your USB-drive.